# Cannot call value of non function type SKShapeNode

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, sprite-kit

I keep trying to fix this error and trying to make the character contain in the row which will be an int.

```
 func isRightTileAt(location:CGPoint) ->Bool {
    //as shape node so we can get fill
    var currentRect = self.atPoint(location) as! SKShapeNode
    //get the 10th character which will contain the row and make it an int
   // let rowOfNode = Int(currentRect.name![10]) //error(tried both of these)
    var rowOfNode = Int(currentRect(name[10])) //error 
    //flip position is used for the row index below the screen to flip it to the top.
    var currentRow = self.flipPosition + 1
    var currentRowOfClick = self.flipPosition

    //we reuse the flip position because it hasn't flipped yet but it normally contains the right row.
    //because flip position happens after this check so it won't be sent back around yet
    if self.flipPosition == 5 {
        currentRowOfClick = 0
    }
    //if they are at least on the right row
    if rowOfNode == currentRowOfClick && currentRect.fillColor.hash == 65536{
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: What is `name`. and also can you show the `atPoint()` method? is that actually returning an SKShapeNode for sure?

Comment: @RyanPoolos atPoint() is an instance method of SKNode class.

Comment: @Bran currentRect is in the best case SKNode or its subclass. You can't use it as a function.

Answer (score 0):

There are several challenges accessing the characters of the `name` property of `SKNode` or an `SKNode` subclass (such as `SKShapeNode`).

First, since `name` is a `String?`, it needs to be unwrapped.

```
guard let string = self.name else {
    return
}
```

Second, you can't access the characters of a `String` with an `Int` subscript; you'll need to use a `String.Index`.

```
// Since Swift is zero based, the 10th element is at index 9; use 10 if you want the 11th character.
let index = string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: 9)
// The 10th character of the name
let char = string[index]
```

Third, you can't directly convert a `Character` to an `Int`. You'll need to convert the character to a `String` and then convert the string to an `Int`.

```
let rowString = String(char)

// Unwrap since Int(string:String) returns nil if the string is not an integer
guard let row = Int(rowString) else {
    return
}
```

At this point, `row` is the 10th character of `name` converted to an `Int`.

Alternatively, you can implement the above as an extension

```
extension String {
    func int(at index:Int) -> Int? {
        let index = self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: index)
        let string = String(self[index])
        return Int(string)
    }
}
```

and use it with

```
guard let name = self.name, let row = name.int(at:9) else {
    return
}
```